# Python : Browser not able to browse URL using selenium

Tags: python, selenium, firefox

I am writing a python script which includes opening up an URL and do some activity on it. I am facing an issue when i execute below code then Firefox browser starts but it is not able to browse URL. What could be wrong here..? 
I also tried to add proxy exception but that isn't solve issue.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('WEBSITE_URL')
```

So, Pls suggest what is wrong here.

Comment: Does it work if you change browser to `browser = webdriver.Chrome('/path/to/chromedriver/')` with https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads?

Comment: Could you share more details? What is `URL`, exception?

Comment: When the browser launches but doesn't do anything, generally that means that there's a mismatch in libraries and browser. Make sure that you have the most up-to-date selenium libraries and drivers and make sure that the browser is up-to-date.

Comment: Hello, Issue has been solved by changing script to below. So, root cause was not providing geckodriver path in my script.

Suggestion from both @Beomi helped. Thanks.


    from selenium import webdriver
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\geckodriver.exe')
    browser.get('URL')